# If I have lazy loading set to false (for now) then does it matter if I include the "virtual" keyword or leave it out?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading, virtual-functions

It's my understanding that if I want to use lazy loading in my EF6 application I should 
code my relationships like this with the last two items marked as virtual:

```
public class Test
{
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public int ExamId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual Exam Exam { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserTest> UserTests { get; set; }
}
```

If I do not want to use lazy loading (at the moment) and if I set the lazyloading configuration to false then are there any performance considerations if I leave in the virtual keyword or should I code my class like this without the keyword ?

```
public class Test
{
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public int ExamId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public Exam Exam { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserTest> UserTests { get; set; }
}
```

The reason I am asking this is I would like to maintain flexibility by keeping in the `virtual` keyword but only if that will not cause any problems for me when I am not using lazy loading.

I read the following

> "if you use the virtual keyword on an ICollection/one-to-many relationship property, it will be lazy-loaded by default, whereas if you leave the virtual keyword out, it will be eager-loaded."

Is this true even if I set `DbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` ?

Comment: If you set it, then eager loading will be done. And virtual keyword means different I think

Comment: What do you mean "if you set it"?

Comment: If you set lazyloadingenabled false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `virtual` keyword just makes it possible that a derived class **can** be created dynamically at runtime which overrides the properties that are marked as `virtual` in order to inject some data access code ("proxy"). But when you set `LazyLoadingEnabled = false` you tell Entity Framework "*Don't override my entity class with a lazy loading proxy*". In that case the `virtual` keyword doesn't have any effect. (Well, I can't actually tell what are the costs of instantiating an object that has `virtual` properties or methods from .NET CLR viewpoint. It probably has some costs, but I'm sure it's almost nothing compared to actually accessing the database.)

So, your approach to mark properties as `virtual` to be open for possible lazy loading in the future is fine in my opinion.

BTW: This - *whereas if you leave the virtual keyword out, it will be eager-loaded* - is wrong. If you disable lazy loading - either by omitting the `virtual` keyword or by setting `LazyLoadingEnable = false` - you don't get eager loading by default. Instead you get no loading (of navigation properties) at all. Eager loading must be coded explicitly by using `Include` or by using projections.

Just to mention it: You can also add the `virtual` modifier later when you need it. And you can limit it to specific entities. EF doesn't consider this as a model change which would touch somehow the database schema.

Answer (score 1):

When you set `LazyLoadingEnabled = False` . It will not affect to lazy loading even you include **virtual** keyword.

**virtual** works together with two properties of `DbContext.Configuration` :

- `ProxyCreationEnabled`

> [MSDN] Gets or sets a value indicating whether or not the framework will
>   create instances of dynamically generated proxy classes whenever it
>   creates an instance of an entity type

- `LazyLoadingEnabled`